# Can “grow/fall 2%” mean grow/fall “to” 2%?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, prepositions

> The rate has grown 2%.

> The rate has fallen 2%.

Here, do they mean the rate has grown/fallen “BY” 2%?

Is it possible if I understand they mean “to” 2%?

Comment: **By** or just an amount, means the number is the amount of increase or decrease; **to** means the number is the final figure.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. Then do those two sentences means “the rate has grow/fallen “BY 2%”? or “TO 2%”?

Comment: They do not mean "to".

Comment: If something ***changes** [grows, shrinks, gains, loses, rises, drops] **some amount*** with no intervening preposition I think ***by*** is *always* implied (never ***to***). That's to say, "some amount" is always the amount of change, not the new value - unless that's explicitly indicated by *changes **to** [new value]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much! 

Answer (score 4):

If a **quantity** grows 2% or grows by 2%, it is 2% bigger after the growth. If it shrinks 2% or shrinks by 2% it is 2% smaller.

> If you had $100, and I give you $2, you now have $102, and your wealth
> has grown (or grown by) 2%. If you give me $2, you now have $98, and
> your wealth has shrunk (or shrunk by) 2%.

Note the difference between [percentages and percentage points](https://thewritingbusiness.com/the-difference-between-percentages-and-percentage-points/#:%7E:text=A%20percentage%20point%20is%20the,as%20a%20fraction%20of%20100.)

If a **percentage** grows (or shrinks) to 2%, that is the final percentage.

> If the government taxed you $4 for every $100 you earned, the tax rate
> was 4%, and if the government now reduces the tax to $2 per $100 earned,
> then the tax rate falls to 2%.